# Hard to resolve issue! :: TypeError: player.loadVideoById is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, youtube-iframe-api

When `$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal'` gets called. I get this:

> TypeError: player.loadVideoById is not a function. (In 'player.loadVideoById(x)', 'player.loadVideoById' is undefined)

https://jsfiddle.net/rdbj3ty1/5/

In JS Fiddle the code works, but when I add it to my code base, it stops working. I have a lot of other js code and CSS code that it must be interfering with. Is there a way to prevent the interference? Maybe wrap my js code with a block or add more specific references? Is namespacing the issue? If so, how do I do that?

I don't really know what to try. I have spent 2 days on this and getting nowhere.

## JS

```
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'novideoid',
      events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
                           });
  }


  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.

  function onPlayerReady(event) {

    $('.open-popup').click(function() {
      event.target.playVideo();
    });

    $('.close-popup').click(function(e) {
      player.stopVideo();
    });

  }

  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
  //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if(event.data === 0) {           
      $('.close.close-popup').click();
    }
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
  
 $(function () { 
 onYouTubeIframeAPIReady();
   $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
     
       var videoId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('video-id');
       var x = new String(videoId);
       player.loadVideoById(x); 

  });

});
```

Comment: I feel like I've seen this already today.

Comment: @TinyGiant, Ya, I have been trouble shooting it all day and once I get through one, issue, I get another issue.  This should be the last of them, if it can get resolved. Please help if you can!

Comment: If it isn't a function that's probably because it isn't ready to be called yet. I'm not familiar with the API but that is usually what happens. Try logging the objects that you're trying to access before you access them with `console.dir` (logs objects as they are and avoids lazy expansion)

Comment: @TinyGiant   var player;
  console.dir(player); gives me an undefined

Comment: Where are you logging it? Before the point where you're accessing it?

Comment: after var player;

Comment: It won't be defined until after `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` is called. After `var player` it won't be defined yet.

Comment: You solved it! I needed to remove the second reference to  onYouTubeIframeAPIReady();